# Where in Vayyikra Rabbah is this mentioned?

Tags: sources-mekorot

In [Sefer HaIkkarim](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_3.16.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the follwoing quote appears:

> Similarly the expression, “a statute forever,” is used in relation to the feasts of Passover and Tabernacles, and yet our Rabbis say in “Vayyikra Rabbah” that all festivals will be abolished except Purim and the Day of Atonement.

Where in Vayyikra Rabbah is this mentioned? Due to my own deficiency, I was unable to locate this quote.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95350/759

Answer (score 1):

The original source for this is in the [Midrash on Mishlei](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Mishlei.9?lang=bi) and in the [Yalkut Shimoni](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.944?lang=he)

> שכל המועדים עתידים בטלים וימי הפורים אינם בטלים לעולם שנאמר (אסתר ט כח) ״וימי
> הפורים האלה לא יעברו מתוך היהודים״
> אמר רבי אלעזר אף יום הכיפורים אינו בטל לעולם שנאמר (ויקרא טז לד )״והיתה זאת לכם לחוקת עולם לכפר על בני ישראל מכל חטאתם אחת בשנה
> ״

I wasn't able to find  this in Vayikra Rabbah so I thought of two possible answers:

a)The editor of the sefer made a mistake and thought this maamar chazal was in Vayikra Rabbah because the Medrash above quotes the posuk
from parshas Achrei Mos which is in in sefer Vayikra.

b) The editor of the sefer confused this Medrash with a similar [Medrash in Vayikra Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.9.7?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi) that says all korbanos will be nullified in the future except for the korban todah