# Where does it say in the future there will only be Purim

Tags: purim

Where does it say that? Zohar is preferred but other answers are acceptable.

Comment: See also [Rambam MT Hilchot Megila 2:18](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952007/jewish/Megillah-vChanukah-Chapter-Two.htm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is only Purim to be celebrated "forever"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95350/why-is-only-purim-to-be-celebrated-forever)

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Yes, thank you, that question didn't come up in my search before I asked mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be thinking of [Midrash Mishlei 9](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Mishlei.9.1?lang=bi)

> That is the good name that she acquired in this world and in the world to come; since all of the holidays are to be nullified in the future but the days of Purim will not be nullified, as it is stated (Esther 9:28), 'And these days of Purim will not be rescinded from the Jews.'" Rabbi Elazar said, "Also Yom Kippur will forever not be nullified, as it is stated, 'And it will be to you for an everlasting statute to atone for the Children of Israel from all of their sins once a year.'"